# How to send a file into an iframe with node-express?

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, request

I want to load a html file into an iframe, with express. A have a < a > tag, and when I click on it, the iframe appears. The frame loads, but I obviously get a "CANNOT GET" message in it, because I don't have the appropriate routing. I have the following code snippets.

index.html:

```
<a id="ASZF">Adatvédelmi Szabályzat</a>

<iframe id="ASZFframe" src="ASZF.html"></iframe>
```

server.js:

```
app.get("/ASZ",function(request, response){
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/ASZ.html"));
});
```

Should I use < a href="?" >, or something else?

Comment: `app.get("/ASZF.html", function(req, res) {...})` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your express is not made aware of that route. Your route should be:

`app.get("/ASZF.html", function(req, res) {...});`

But you probably want to look into `serve-static` instead of creating a controller just for this.

Comment: It was the first thing I tried but it doesn't work :/

Comment: the path is relative, so maybe it's not the one you are expecting to see. Add some debugging in `express` to make sure the iframe's URL is the one you think, or make it absolute. Open your devTool and see what is the URL that is requested for that iframe.